# Implement async/await in sort function of arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, promise, async-await, protractor

I am trying to implement a sort method on protractor `ElementArrayFinder`. As known, all protractor methods return promises.
So my sort method has a condition which depends on promises resolution. 
I am using a node plugin for `async/await` in order to make it compatible with node.js versions lower than 6. 
(Here the plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait)

Here my code, where `this` is the `ArrayElementFinder`:

```
var asyncCompare = async(function(a, b) {
    let x = await (a.getText());
    let y = await (b.getText());
    console.log(x.localeCompare(y));
    return x.localeCompare(y);
});

var sortTheArray = async(function(arrayOfElementFinders) {
    return await (arrayOfElementFinders.sort(asyncCompare));
});

this.then((elements) => {
    let arrayOfElementFinders = [elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]];
    let sortedArray = sortTheArray(arrayOfElementFinders);
    console.log('array sorted');
});
```

Unfortunately the timing execution is not the one I expect. The print: `array sorted` happens before than the prints of comparing `x.localeCompare(y)`.
Any idea what am I doing wrong? And any idea how to achieve my objective?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Array.prototype.sort is a synchronous function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) does not take an asynchronous callback. It expects a numeric value as the return value, not a promise for one; and it does return an array not a promise. There's no way around this (though one could implement a custom asynchronous sorting algorithm - even a parallel one).

But that's pretty inefficient anyway. Doing asynchronous fetching of compare values in every sort step will be slow - and it will fetch the same value per element multiple times. Don't do that. Instead, use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to fetch the values to sort by before, then sort (synchronously), then use the results.

You should do

```
const elements = await this;
const arrayOfElementFinders = elements.slice(0, 3); // or Array.from?
const comparableArray = await Promise.all(arrayOfElementFinders.map(async x => [await x.getText(), x]));
comparableArray.sort((a, b) => +(a[0] > b[0]) || -(a[0] < b[0]));
const sortedArray = comparableArray.map(x => x[1]);
console.log('array sorted');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bergi. So actually your suggestion is to retrieve my comparing values manually using async code (through promises for example) and then use a sync sort function which returns these values I computed before?

Comment: @quirimmo Yes, exactly that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your spot and your answer, really nice one and really useful. Unfortunately I cannot get it work. Two main issues: 1) at the moment I am getting back 3 `undefined` from the code above: `[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]` . 2) I would like to get rid of `async/await` and just use promises, and maybe the third party library I am using for the implementation is the reason of the first issue too. Any idea please? Thanks a lot again

Comment: This is what I did so far for changing it with promises. Sorry for the bad formatting but here in the comments is awful. `this.then((elements) => {
        const arrayOfElementFinders = elements.slice(0, 3); // or Array.from?
        const comparableArray = Promise.all(arrayOfElementFinders.map(async((x) => [await(x.getText(), x)])));
        comparableArray.then((arr) => {
            arr.sort((a, b) => +(a[0] > b[0]) || -(a[0] < b[0]));
            const sortedArray = arr.map(x => x[1]);
            console.log(sortedArray);
        });
    });`

Comment: Where do the `undefined`s happen, in `arrayOfElementFinders` (maybe my `slice()` call doesn't work), or `comparableArray` or in `sortedArray`? Regarding `async`/`await`, you can of course replace them with `then()` callbacks, but I don't see any reason to do that when they're available.

Comment: Because unfortunately in node <= 6 they are not available by default I would like to get rid of the third party library. Do you suggest me to keep them and use this third party library? I think the slice should work fine because from 8 elements I got 3 elements. It happens inside the `then` of the `comparableArray`. I am doing a bit of debug to see what's going on. Thanks again for your help, your tips and your time

Comment: Yep I confirm that the slice works fine. Just tested it. Could I ask  you why from the `map` you return an array with the `x.getText()` and the `x` as well please? `arrayOfElementFinders.map((x) => [x.getText(), x])`

Comment: @quirimmo Do whatever you think is easier, I don't know what tradeoffs the third-party-library has for you. Regarding the `undefined`s, you mis-placed some parentheses in the callback - it's `async x => [(await x.getText()), x]` not `async x => [await(x.getText(), x)]`. Or `x => x.getText().then(r => [r, x])` if you want.

Comment: oh ok thanks a lot I think I got why you keep both the `x.getText` and the `x` element, so I always have also a reference to the element and not only to the resolved text from the promise. Is it correct?

Comment: At the end I did everything with the following implementation: `const comparableArray = await(Promise.all(elements.map(async((x) => [await(x.getText()), x]))));
            comparableArray.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
            const sortedArray = comparableArray.map(x => x[1]);`

Comment: I take my hat off to you Sir! Thanks a lot for your time, for your help and for your wonderful tips! +100 if I could

Answer (score 1):

Does it not support promises before V6?

I dislike mixing imperative `await` with functional `promise` abstraction. Wouldn't you be able to do like?

```js
Promise.all([Promise.resolve(10), Promise.resolve(4), Promise.resolve(7)])
       .then(r => r.sort((a,b) => a-b))
       .then(s => console.log(s));
```

ans splatter `.catch()` stages as needed?

Comment: Hi @Redu thanks for your reply. 
Yes it does support ES6 Promises in the V6, but I don't remember since which version node supports es6 promises. 
Btw using protractor you "should" use their native implementation of promises: `protractor.promise`
I am trying to avoid to use ES6 promises, even if so much better than the standard ones provided by protractor

Answer (score 1):

I can see the use of this in cases where the sort function is user-facing and someone is, for example, being shown two pictures and has to pick one over another. In this case it's possible to just re-run the sort function over and over again until you have the precedence of all items the sort-function needs to fully sort your array.

This function could look something like this:

```js
type Box<T> = {  value: T };

const sortAsync = async <T>(
    arr: T[],
    cmp: (a: T, b: T) => Promise<number>
): Promise<T[]> => {

    // Keep a list of two values and the precedence
    const results: [Box<T>, Box<T>, number][] = [];

    // Box the value in case you're sorting primitive values and some
    // values occur more than once.
    const result: Box<T>[] = arr.map(value => ({ value }));

    for (; ;) {
        let nextA: Box<T>, nextB: Box<T>, requiresSample = false;

        result.sort((a, b) => {

            // Check if we have to get the precedence of a value anyways,
            // so we can skip this one.
            if (requiresSample) return 0;

            // See if we already now which item should take precedence
            const match = results.find(v => v[0] === a && v[1] === b);
            if (match) return match[2];

            // We need the precedence of these two elements
            nextA = a;
            nextB = b;
            requiresSample = true;
            return 0;
        });

        if (requiresSample) {
            // Let the async function calculate the next value
            results.push([nextA, nextB, await cmp(nextA.value, nextB.value)]);
        } else break; // It's fully sorted
    }

    // Map the sorted boxed-value array to its containing value back again
    return result.map(v => v.value);
};
```

For simplicity (and the sake of immutability) I don't modify the original array and just return a new one:

```js
// Create new array and shuffle the values in it
const values = new Array(20)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, index) => index)
    .sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

console.log('Start: ', values);

const sorted = await sortAsync(values, async (a, b) => {
    // Simulate an async task by waiting some time
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 25));
    return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log('End: ', sorted);
```