# Sort function not working on firebase .onSnapshot for chat app

Tags: arrays, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The actual list where I'm sorting by yDS1a41FxzZlTjVvzxjteKSHSn22:

```
yDS1a41FxzZlTjVvzxjteKSHSn22: 1571361291153
id: "t4ImLnwtFU5e7VKcCmm4"
photoUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.*"
startDate: "2019-10-17"
unread: []
userId: "FxttC8c66QXMElHIkBFApVVGevy1"
```

I have a chat app that uses Cloud Firestore as a backend.  I'm using a dynamic property on the chat app so I can't order by in my Firestore query, I have to do it once I pull the data from Firestore and store it in an array.  The problem is that it's not sorting by time desc once I store the data in the array.

```
qry
        .onSnapshot((val) => {
          val.forEach(snp => {
            if (snap.data().likes.includes(snp.id)) {
              this.users.push({
                id: snp.id,
                userId: snp.data().userId,
                unread: snap.data().unread,
                [this.loggedInUser.uid]: snp.data()[this.loggedInUser.uid],
              });
              console.log('log', this.users);
            }
            // remove any unique items
            this.users = Array.from(new Set(this.users.map(a => a.id)))
            .map(id => {
              return this.users.find(a => a.id === id);
            });
          });
          this.getPhotoUrl();
          this.checkIfUnread();
                    let test = this.users.sort((a, b) => (a[this.loggedInUser.uid] < b[this.loggedInUser.uid]) ? 1 : -1);

        });
```

So if you send a message and you go back to the main message screen it should sort the messages by the last message sent...it's ignoring the sort all together.

Comment: If the `this.users.sort(...)` doesn't work, can you reproduce this problem with a hardcoded list of elements? If so, including that in your question makes it much easier for us to help, since we can try it out ourselves easily.

Comment: I added a snippet of the list.  But I think the problem is where I'm performing the sorting action.  For example, when I use a different variable in the HTML:

let test = this.travelBuddies.sort

  <ion-list *ngFor="let testList of test">

the list is blank.  I think the problem is where I'm sorting the list in relation to the firebase query.  I think the DOM is being rendered before the sort is actually finished.

Comment: I actually see the problem.  When I send a message I have a firebase function that adds a time stamp to the document that I'm using to sort.  If I close the app and go into the page again then they're sorted.  But browsing from the chat back to the message list doesn't refresh or invoke ngOnit in order to pull the day from firebase and resort based on that timestamp.

Comment: you need to handle it differently using async and await. As `firestore/firebase`operations return a promise. Did you get it! Sorting does take time and `onSnapshot` does not wait for it. Please refer to this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45661316/9739044