# How to sort sequence based on a coroutine?

Tags: python, sorting, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

With a naive implementation like:

```
import asyncio

async def get_priority(value):
    # Simulate sending out network request.
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return value

values = [1, 2, 3]
sorted_values = await sorted(values, key=get_priority)
```

(assume that the top-level `await` was wrapped in an `async def`)

`sorted` assumes that the key function is synchronous, and it will try to compare the coroutines themselves instead of the underlying values, leading to a `TypeError`.

How can I sort a sequence when I want the key function to be a coroutine? I could write the `sorted` implementation myself, but specifically wondering if I can somehow extract the asynchronous key computations outside of `sorted` using `asyncio`, so I can stick to standard lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up stumbling upon [Implement async/await in sort function of arrays javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45661316/5319267), which referenced a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), where the priorities to sort the values by are precomputed and stored alongside the original values. Below is an implementation in Python:

```
import asyncio
from operator import itemgetter

async def get_priority(value):
    # Simulate sending out network request.
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return value

values = [1, 2, 3]
value_priorities = await asyncio.gather(*map(get_priority, values))
sorted_values = [value for value, _ in sorted(
    zip(values, value_priorities),
    key=itemgetter(1)
)]
```