# JavaScript Array.sort: Show progress indicator

Tags: javascript

I'm sorting a large array and want to update the UI in my web app while `sort` is running. In my custom comparison function, I'm updating the HTML content every 10,000 (or so) comparisons, but the browser doesn't reflect these changes.

```
large_array.sort( (a,b) => {
    ++comparisons
    if( comparisons % 10000 == 0 ) {
        // this works:
        console.log(comparisons)
        // this doesn't:
        document.querySelector('#sort-progress').textContent = comparisons
    }
    return custom_sort(a,b)
})
```

What I've found is that using web workers should be the "correct" solution, but that would mean to completely redesign the application. So I hope to find some workaround.

Comment: Also see: [MDN - async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: @Roberto - `sort` callbacks can't be `async` functions. Of course, if you implement a *custom* sort...

Comment: To clarify:: [Implement async/await in sort function of arrays javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45661316/943435)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current approach doesn't work because the JavaScript code runs on the main UI thread, and ties it up until the `sort` is complete, so the browser can't update the page display until the `sort` is over and the JavaScript code finishes running, allowing the event loop to complete.

A few options come to mind:

1. Use a web worker (as you indicated).
2. Sort the array in chunks, yielding back to allow the browser to repaint before triggering sorting the next chunk with `setTimeout(..., 0)` or similar. Don't yield too often or you'll end up taking forever to sort the result, but every once in a while should be good.

   - One way to do that is to write your own sort function (perhaps implementing a [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)) and implement it as an `async` function, occasionally (for instance, roughly every 10,000 elements) yielding to allow the browser to perform display updates by doing `await delay(0)` where `delay` is [a wrapper for `setTimeout`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout/22707551#22707551).

> What I've found is that using web workers should be the "correct" solution, but that would mean to completely redesign the application

That will depend a lot on what you're sorting. If you're sorting anything [transferrable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects) or that can be serialized with the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), it shouldn't be necessary to completely redesign the application just for this. You need to:

1. `postMessage` the array to the worker (*transferring* if possible).
2. Have the worker send updates on its progress that you use to update the UI.
3. Have the worker `postMessage` the sorted array back to your code.

But if what's in the array can't be handled that way, there will indeed be more work involved. For instance, you might:

1. Build a new array containing only the information needed for sorting purposes, along with the original index of each object in the array.
2. `postMessage` that array to the web worker.
3. Have the worker send updates on its progress that you use to update the UI.
4. Have the worker `postMessage` the sorted array back to your code.
5. Loop through the received array either putting the elements in the place they should go (e.g., doing swap operations), or building a new array with the elements in the order they should go.

That said, though, implementing Timsort as an `async` function with periodic pauses may well be simpler.