# Async version of sort function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, asynchronous

Found this question [Implement async/await in sort function of arrays javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45661247/387194) but mine is different.

I want to implement async version of the sort function. for my programming language that compiles to JavaScript called [Gaiman](https://github.com/jcubic/gaiman) where everything is async by default. This make the code way simpler. Some things can be really asynchronuios like reading the input from user but all functions defined in Gaiman are async even if they don't use anything that is really asynchronous.

I've implemented custom class that extend Array:

```js
function is_function(obj) {
    return typeof obj === 'function';
}

function is_promise(obj) {
    return obj && is_function(obj.then);
}

class GaimanArray extends Array {
    map(...args) {
        function call(arr) {
            return new GaimanArray(...arr);
        }
        const arr = super.map.apply(this, args);
        const some = super.some;
        const has_promise = some.call(arr, is_promise);
        if (has_promise) {
            return Promise.all(arr).then(call);
        } else {
            return call(arr);
        }
    }
    forEach(...args) {
        return this.map(...args);
    }
    filter(fn, ctx) {
        const filter = super.filter;
        function call(arr) {
            return new GaimanArray(...filter.call(arr, x => x));
        }
        const items = this.map(fn, ctx);
        if (is_promise(items)) {
            return items.then(arr => {
                return call(arr);
            });
        } else {
            return call(items);
        }
    }
    reduce(fn, init) {
        return super.reduce.call(this, function(acc, ...args) {
            if (is_promise(acc)) {
                return acc.then(acc => {
                    return fn(acc, ...args);
                });
            } else {
                return fn(acc, ...args);
            }
        }, init);
    }
    sort() {
    }
    some(fn, ctx) {
        const some = super.some;
        return this.mapWithCallback(fn, (arr) => {
            return some.call(arr, x => x);
        }, ctx);
    }
    every(fn, ctx) {
        const every = super.every;
        return this.mapWithCallback(fn, (arr) => {
            return every.call(arr, x => x);
        }, ctx);
    }
    find(fn, ctx) {
        return this.mapWithCallback(fn, (arr) => {
            const index = arr.findIndex(x => x);
            return this[index];
        }, ctx);
    }
    flatMap(fn, ...args) {
        return this.map(...args).flat();
    }
    mapWithCallback(fn, callback, ctx) {
        const items = this.map(fn, ctx);
        if (is_promise(items)) {
            return items.then(arr => {
                return callback(arr);
            });
        } else {
            return callback(items);
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of methods in my array actually makes the promise-based function optional, this is a leftover implementation when I was modifying Array.prototype but it gives problems with some other library that was executing `args.some(is_promise)`.

I think that I can't use Schwartzian transform because I can't get value for each item, my comparison function needs to be really async.

So how can I implement async sort in JavaScript? Every method is working with async functions except I have no idea how to implement sort.

Comment: constructors are async too? just curious

Comment: @BrunoPolo no constructors are not, because the user can't define classes, but probably can use functions as constructors, I need to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I've created working code based on Rosseta Code:

```js
// based on: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#JavaScript
async function mergeSort(array, fn) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
        return array;
    }
    const mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2),
          left = array.slice(0, mid), right = array.slice(mid);
    await mergeSort(left, fn);
    await mergeSort(right, fn);
    let ia = 0, il = 0, ir = 0;
    while (il < left.length && ir < right.length) {
        array[ia++] = (await fn(left[il], right[ir]) <= 0) ? left[il++] : right[ir++];
    }
    while (il < left.length) {
        array[ia++] = left[il++];
    }
    while (ir < right.length) {
        array[ia++] = right[ir++];
    }
    return array;
}
```