# How to define default JavaScript sort callback function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm attempting to create my own sort function (question [Async version of sort function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72367042/387194)). I've taken merge sort function from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#JavaScript) and make it async:

```js
// based on: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#JavaScript
async function mergeSort(fn, array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
        return array;
    }
    const mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2),
          left = array.slice(0, mid), right = array.slice(mid);
    await mergeSort(fn, left)
    await mergeSort(fn, right)
    let ia = 0, il = 0, ir = 0;
    while (il < left.length && ir < right.length) {
        array[ia++] = (await fn(left[il], right[ir]) <= 0) ? left[il++] : right[ir++];
    }
    while (il < left.length) {
        array[ia++] = left[il++];
    }
    while (ir < right.length) {
        array[ia++] = right[ir++];
    }
    return array;
}
```

But I'm not sure how I can define default function fn to work the same as in JavaScript.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 100, 20].sort());
```

What should be the default sorting function to match those in the JavaScript engine?
Should I convert numbers to strings and compare those? What is the proper implementation?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, there is an example of `a.localeCompare(b);` but this is not the default behavior of a sort function.

Comment: ...it describes the default behaviour, without a compare function. See also https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort.

Comment: So the background of the async sorting is irrelevant to the question? Is this really just asking "what would be the callback passed to `sort` to get the default behaviour?"

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks I think I get it, I'll add an answer with my function.

Comment: @trincot yes. But I wanted to give context, if I would ask without the context, the question would be why I need such function.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

The default `sort` method as defined in core.js looks like so

```
var getSortCompare = function (comparefn) {
  return function (x, y) {
    if (y === undefined) return -1;
    if (x === undefined) return 1;
    if (comparefn !== undefined) return +comparefn(x, y) || 0;
    return toString(x) > toString(y) ? 1 : -1;
  };
```

Taken from this repo: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.sort.js

Comment: Ok, but the question is what compare should look like if not defined. If you look at my code it's exactly the same, only variable names are different.

Comment: Just add a default value for the parameter, I'll update the answer.

Comment: This is not a proper compare function, because it will work as expected sporting numbers in order, which is not how JavaScript sorting works. JavaScript sorts method sorts numbers alphabetically.

Comment: @jcubic here is the link to the source code: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.sort.js

Comment: Thanks, now it looks like a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jonrsharpe comments I was able to implement proper default function:

```js
function defaultSortFn(a, b) {
    if (typeof a !== 'string') {
        a = String(a);
    }
    if (typeof b !== 'string') {
        b = String(b);
    }
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

that can be used in my sort:

```js
Array.prototype.sort = function(fn = defaultSortFn) {
   return mergeSort(fn, this);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript specification for [Arra.prototype.sort](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) mentions that the comparison (in absence of a comparator) involves:

> e. Let *xString* be ? ToString(*x*).
> f. Let *yString* be ? ToString(*y*).
> g. Let *xSmaller* be ! IsLessThan(*xString*, *yString*, **true**).
> h. If *xSmaller* is true, return **-1**.
> i. Let *ySmaller* be ! IsLessThan(*yString*, *xString*, **true**).
> j. If *ySmaller* is true, return **1**.
> k. Return **+0**.

Given that the IsLessThan procedure is also executed when two strings are compared with the [`<`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) operator, we can faithfully replicate the default callback function as follows:

```
function (x, y) {
    let xString = String(x);
    let yString = String(y);
    return xString < yString ? -1 : yString < xString ? 1 : 0;
}
```